# Is there a way to publish a ROS AnyMsg in Python?

Tags: ros, python, python3

I am trying to publish a rospy.msg.AnyMsg by doing the following:

```
import rospy
.
.
.
publisher = rospy.Publisher('jason_topic',
                            rospy.msg.AnyMsg,
                            queue_size=10)

publisher.publish(ros_message)
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subscriber_any.py", line 26, in <module>
    publisher.publish(ros_message)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 879, in publish
    data = args_kwds_to_message(self.data_class, args, kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 118, in args_kwds_to_message
    if len(data_class._slot_types) == 0:
AttributeError: type object 'AnyMsg' has no attribute '_slot_types'
```

I did a `print(dir(rospy.msg.AnyMsg()))` and verified that there was no attribute _slot_types. Is what I am trying to do possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how `AnyMsg` is intended to be used, and I wouldn't expect it to be possible to do this. As the error message shows, `AnyMsg` is missing key attributes that are required for being published: it's only useful for *subscribers*, so you can subscribe to anything and access the raw data. `AnyMsg` is usually not the tool you want to be using, though. If you have the message you want to use, you should use it.

If your goal is to publish to a topic when you don't have the message beforehand, you can:

1. Subscribe to the topic using `AnyMsg`
2. Use this newly constructed subscriber to get the topic's message type
3. Use this message type to construct a publisher
4. Use `genpy` to dynamically construct the message

...But you probably don't need (or want) to do anything that complicated: just use the correct message type whenever possible.

Comment: Is genpy strictly a command line tool?

Comment: genpy is not a command line tool, no: it's a python library that does some of the behind-the-scenes ROS message generation for python. See https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/genpy/html/index.html

Comment: Do you know of an example of how to use genpy to dynamically construct the message? Would I have to import the genpy.Message type classes?

Comment: I don't know of one, but if you ask a question about how to 'publish on a ros topic when the message type is not known' and link it here, I'll make a python snippet and provide it.

Comment: here is the link. [link](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105784/how-do-you-publish-on-a-ros-topic-when-the-message-type-is-not-known)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Only fully defined message types can be published, as the ROS middleware requires each topic to have a fixed message type. Once a type is established for a topic, attempts to use a different type will fail (something like `Could not process inbound connection: topic types do not match`). You have 2 options:

1. Use a fully defined message type if possible.
2. If your data is truly dynamic, i.e. if the data schema is not fixed, then you can do something like using `std_msgs/String` with the `data` field being arbitrary JSON data. You would have to convert your message into JSON first though.

```py
import rospy
from rospy_message_converter import json_message_converter
from std_msgs.msg import String

pub = rospy.Publisher(
    'jason_topic', String, queue_size=10
)
pub.publish(
    data=json_message_converter.convert_ros_message_to_json(msg)
)
```

I would strongly recommend option (1) because most ROS tooling cannot handle things like option (2). I would only use option (2) if you're sending arbitrary unstructured blobs over messages.